# skills required for software development/engineering?

Tags: software-design

What are the skills to be learned for software development or software engineering? And what projects can one do ?Are the projects like Library Management System or School management system are all we can do ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This question isn't on-topic or in-scope for Stack Overflow. (But of course you can do more than just library or school management. All the software you've ever used was written b software developers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you wanna be specialized.
I strongly recommend *"Java"*, because it´s a object-oriented language and is used in several different type of hardwares.

Comment: what are the different fields that you mentioned?